# Why am I seeing cache misses against the UpdateTimestampsCache?

Tags: spring, hibernate, ehcache, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Could someone please explain to me why when using the ehCache monitor am I seeing cache misses against the UpdateTimestampsCache? I don't see misses against any of my other caches, and actually I don't see any cached entries in the UpdateTimestampsCache.... I must be doing SOMETHING wrong. FYI, may application is a Spring Boot application using Spring Data JPA and a couple custom finder methods in a couple repositories that I've tagged as cacheable. I have query caching enabled. I have query cache and updatetimestampscache configured in ehcache.xml:

```
<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache" maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="3600"
   overflowToDisk="true" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" transactionalMode="off"
   statistics="true"/>
<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache" maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" timeToIdleSeconds="3600"
       eternal="true" overflowToDisk="true" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" transactionalMode="off"
       statistics="true">
</cache>
```

Here's an example of one of my Repository classes and a custom finder method:

```
public interface PromotionServiceXrefRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<PromotionServiceXref, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT psx FROM Customer c " +
            "JOIN c.customerProductPromotions cpp " +
            "JOIN cpp.productPromotion pp " +
            "JOIN pp.promotion p JOIN p.promotionServiceXrefs psx " +
            "WHERE c.sonosId = ?1")
    @QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true"))
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region = "promotionServiceXrefByCustomerId")
    Set<PromotionServiceXref> findByCustomerId(int customerId);
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find out why? I am having the same issue now?

Comment: I don't remember ever finding a good answer and I stopped worrying about it. Sorry!